# MySQL - counting records based on rolling dates

Tags: mysql

In a table with just two columns ( `id` and `dt` ) I want to count the number of unique user_id's that logged in (dt is login date) in the past 3 days for any given date. This is a sample of my data:

```
id  dt
user_10 2015-09-01
user_9  2015-09-01
user_4  2015-09-01
user_8  2015-09-01
user_8  2015-09-02
user_9  2015-09-02
user_1  2015-09-02
user_6  2015-09-02
user_7  2015-09-03
user_3  2015-09-03
user_8  2015-09-03
user_10 2015-09-03
user_10 2015-09-04
user_9  2015-09-04
user_8  2015-09-04
user_4  2015-09-04
user_8  2015-09-04
user_6  2015-09-04
```

The expected output is this:

```
day count
2015-09-01  3
2015-09-02  5
2015-09-03  7
2015-09-04  8
```

Here is a link to sqlfidle with this data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecda9
I tried several approaches, bu I was only able to get the correct result for the first day in the data:

```
select t1.dt, count(distinct(t1.id)) from t as t1 INNER JOIN t t2
ON datediff(t1.dt,t2.dt)<=2
GROUP BY t1.dt
order by t1.dt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.dt
     , COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) n 
  FROM t a 
  JOIN t b 
    ON b.dt BETWEEN a.dt - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND a.dt 
 GROUP 
    BY a.dt;
```

or adapting your solution...

```
select t1.dt
     , count(distinct(t2.id)) 
  from t as t1 
  JOIN t t2
    ON datediff(t1.dt,t2.dt) BETWEEN 0 AND 2
 GROUP 
    BY t1.dt
 order 
    by t1.dt;
```